# Customer ActionFilterAttribute OnActionExecuting override never called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes, onactionexecuting

I'm using MVC 4.

I code this customer attribute that inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute`

```
public class AuthorizedAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{    
    public AccessLevel Threshold { get; set; }

    public AuthorizedAttribute()
    {
        Threshold = AccessLevel.Anonymous;
    }

    public AuthorizedAttribute(AccessLevel threshold)
    {
        Threshold = threshold;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //some actions
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And I'm using it on action `Manage` in my `UserController`

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorized(AccessLevel.Administrator)]
    public ViewResult Manage()
    {
         return View();
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint in my attribute contructor, in the overrided method `OnActionExecuting` and in my `UserController` and when I call the action url through my browser in debug mode only my controller breakpoint is firing and I land on the page even I'm not authenticated..
What am I doing wrong ?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear that I wasn't completly in MVC 4 but almost in MVC 5. I just need to do a little update on my web.config to resolve my issue.. 
I found my salvation [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. Probably you have troubles in the routing or etc.

Comment: No my routing is good, my breakpoint in my controller methods is firing, but not those in my attribute..

Comment: in this case I can figure it out only if i take a look on this functionality on the project.

Comment: Which other information do you need to know if it's ok or not ?